# Getting segmentation fault while implementing Kosaraju Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory

**kosaraju algorithm:**
Problem statement:  **Given a Directed Graph with V vertices (Numbered from 0 to V-1) and E edges, Find the number of strongly connected components in the graph.**
while implementing this code I am getting a segmentation fault. Where is the error in this code?

```
   void dfs(int node,vector<int>adj[],stack<int>&st,vector<int>&vis){
    vis[node]=1;
    for(auto it: adj[node]){
        if(!vis[it]){
            dfs(it,adj,st,vis);
           
        }
    }
     st.push(node);
}

void revdfs(int node,vector<int>trs[],vector<int>&vis){
      vis[node]=1;
    for(auto it: trs[node]){
        if(!vis[it]){
            revdfs(it,trs,vis);
           
        }
    }
    
}

int kosaraju(int V, vector<int> adj[])
{
    stack<int>st;
    vector<int>vis(V+1,0);
    
    for(int i=0; i<V;i++){
        if(!vis[i])
        dfs(i,adj,st,vis);
    }
    
 
    int cnt=0;
    
vector<int> transpose[V+1]; 

for(int i = 1;i<=V;i++) {
    vis[i] = 0; 
    for(auto it: adj[i]) {
        transpose[it].push_back(i); 
    }
}

    while(!st.empty()){
        int node=st.top();
        st.pop();
        if(!vis[node]){
            cnt++;
            revdfs(node,transpose,vis);
        }
    }
    return cnt;
```

Comment: Start by 1. formatting your code properly, 2. giving the line number where the segfault occurs, 3. provide the inputs that cause the segfault, and ideally, 4. remove the parts of the code that aren't relevant to the problem you're facing.

Comment: "Where is the error in this code?" to answer this question you should use a debugger.  This will tell where the fault occurs.  Often, that is enough to make the fix obvious.  If not, THEN you can ask a question.